# different pages on change of group in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

My report groups contains 4-5 table component which will be printed each time when group changed.I don't want to print multiple entries of same group in the table components inside the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textField>
                    <reportElement   x="150" y="0" width="60" height="20" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" />//**isPrintRepeatedValues="false"** 

                    <textElement  textAlignment="Left">
                        <font isBold="false"  isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{activityname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>


<textField>
```